# D365 Display deeply related information on a form in subgrid

Tags: dynamics-365, fetchxml

Have a requirement to show list of Unterweisung (trainings) titles in Contact's form as a subgrid. Please, look at:

[image]

Is there a way to display those?

I have tried to append `fetchXML` to form grid vie JS, but no success there by two reasons:

1) `FetchXML` is not valid, because of twin-linked entity search, i suppose. If it is not supported, the whole approach is wrong.

2) Even if leaving filtering only for one entity, d365 drops an error `Invalid FetchXML` on opening Contact form. `FetchXML validators` are stating opposite.

Estimated full fetchXML (not valid):

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="new_schulungstyp">
    <attribute name="new_name" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="new_schulungstypid" />
    <attribute name="new_typ" />
    <attribute name="new_intervall" />
    <order attribute="createdon" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="new_new_schulungstyp_new_azttigkeit" from="new_schulungstypid" to="new_schulungstypid" visible="false" intersect="true">
      <link-entity name="new_azttigkeit" from="new_azttigkeitid" to="new_azttigkeitid" alias="aa">
        <link-entity name="new_new_profil_new_azttigkeit" from="new_azttigkeitid" to="new_azttigkeitid" visible="false" intersect="true">
          <link-entity name="new_profil" from="new_profilid" to="new_profilid" alias="ab">
            <link-entity name="new_contact_new_profil" from="new_profilid" to="new_profilid" visible="false" intersect="true">
              <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="contactid" alias="ac">
                <filter type="or">
                  <condition attribute="contactid" operator="eq" value="currentContactIdInsertedViaJs" />
                </filter>
              </link-entity>
            </link-entity>
          </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
    <link-entity name="new_new_betriebsmittel_new_schulungstyp" from="new_schulungstypid" to="new_schulungstypid" visible="false" intersect="true">
      <link-entity name="new_betriebsmittel" from="new_betriebsmittelid" to="new_betriebsmittelid" alias="ad">
        <link-entity name="new_new_betriebsmittel_new_profil" from="new_betriebsmittelid" to="new_betriebsmittelid" visible="false" intersect="true">
          <link-entity name="new_profil" from="new_profilid" to="new_profilid" alias="ae">
            <link-entity name="new_contact_new_profil" from="new_profilid" to="new_profilid" visible="false" intersect="true">
              <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="contactid" alias="af">
                <filter type="or">
                  <condition attribute="contactid" operator="eq" value="currentContactIdInsertedViaJs" />
                </filter>
              </link-entity>
            </link-entity>
          </link-entity>
        </link-entity>
      </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

JS code with single entity filter:

```
function filterTrainings(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var guid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    var fullname = formContext.getAttribute("fullname").getValue();

    //var fullName = formContext.getAttribute("fullname_d").getValue();
var fetchXML = "<fetch>";
    fetchXML+=  "<entity name='new_schulungstyp'>";
    fetchXML+= "<attribute name='new_name' />";
    fetchXML+= "<attribute name='createdon' />";
    fetchXML+= "<attribute name='new_schulungstypid' />";
    fetchXML+= "<attribute name='new_typ' />";
    fetchXML+= "<attribute name='new_intervall' />";
    fetchXML+= "<order attribute='createdon' descending='false' />";
    fetchXML+= "<filter type='and'>";
    fetchXML+= "<condition attribute='statecode' operator='eq' value='0' />";
    fetchXML+=  "</filter>";
    fetchXML+= "<link-entity name='new_new_schulungstyp_new_azttigkeit' from='new_schulungstypid' to='new_schulungstypid' visible='false' intersect='true'>";
    fetchXML+= "<link-entity name='new_azttigkeit' from='new_azttigkeitid' to='new_azttigkeitid' alias='aj'>";
    fetchXML+= "<link-entity name='new_new_profil_new_azttigkeit' from='new_azttigkeitid' to='new_azttigkeitid' visible='false' intersect='true'>";
    fetchXML+= "<link-entity name='new_profil' from='new_profilid' to='new_profilid' alias='ak'>";
    fetchXML+= "<link-entity name='new_contact_new_profil' from='new_profilid' to='new_profilid' visible='false' intersect='true'>";
    fetchXML+= "<link-entity name='contact' from='contactid' to='contactid' alias='al'>";
    fetchXML+= "<filter type='and'>";
    fetchXML+= "<condition attribute='contactid' operator='eq' value='"+guid+"' />";
    fetchXML+= "</filter>";
    fetchXML+=  "</link-entity>";
    fetchXML+=  "</link-entity>";
    fetchXML+= "</link-entity>";
    fetchXML+=  "</link-entity>";
    fetchXML+= "</link-entity>";
    fetchXML+=  "</link-entity>";
    fetchXML+=  "</entity>";
    fetchXML+=  "</fetch>";

    var grid = formContext.getControl("relatedTrainings");

    if (grid == null) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            filterTrainings(executionContext);
        }, 2000);
        return;
    } else {
        grid.getGrid().setParameter("fetchXml", filterTrainings); //set the fetch xml to the sub grid
        console.log("refresh............")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have few questions. Is you fetchxml valid? Have you tested it using Fetchxml builder. Then can you create new temporary view on ´new_schulungstyp` Entity and use View Designer (plugin from XRMToolbox), If your fetchxml is correct you can add this fetchxml to your view Designer.
Also can you just link `new_schulungstyp` to 1 link entity down and then go step by step so that rather than adding all links you go one hierarchy down.

Comment: Hello, The second (single entity filter) fetchXML is valid. Though D365 drops an error when attaching it to the subgrid via JS. The first one is crashing when trying to get results in Advanced Search, but logically it is something I need.  I will try View Designer as You suggested. Didn't get what You meant  by "You just link new_schulungstyp to 1 link entity down and then go step by step so that rather than adding all links you go one hierarchy down".

Comment: when you create/updated view with injecting fetchxml or update view with view designer (injecting fetchxml) you will not see this in Advanced find. Advanced find will simply break for that view but when you go on Entity and select a view it shall work. As mentioned try to create a temp view and play over there rather than directly injecting with Js.

Comment: Thank You, I will try that out when I'll reach that project.

Comment: Did you managed to move ahead with it?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure that one out. I am getting all required ID's that should be displayed in subgrid by subsequently sending get requests. Most important here is to manage async nature of promises. Then I build a filter that forces subgrid to show only entities, that are in related ID collection

Posting my solution:

```
function filterTrainings(executionContext) {
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
var trainigsControl = formContext.getControl("relatedTrainings").getGrid();
var guid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
console.log(guid);

var relatedProfiles = [];
var relatedTatigkeiten = [];
var relatedBetriebsmittelGruppen = [];
var unterweisungTypen = [];
var xml;

GetRelatedProfiles()
    .then(() => GetRelatedTatigkeiten().then(GetTatigkeitenRelatedUnterweisungTypen).then(() => GetRelatedBetriebsmittel().then(GetBetriebsmittelRelatedUnterweisungTypen).then(buildFetchXMLAndUpdateGrid)));

function buildFetchXMLAndUpdateGrid() {
    getUniques(unterweisungTypen);
    var values = unterweisungTypen.map(val => `<value>${val}</value>`);
    console.log(values);

    xml = `<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
    <entity name="new_schulungstyp">
        <attribute name="new_name" />
        <attribute name="createdon" />
        <attribute name="new_schulungstypid" />
        <attribute name="new_typ" />
        <attribute name="new_intervall" />
        <order attribute="createdon" descending="false" />
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="new_schulungstypid" operator="in">${values.join('')}</condition>
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>`;
    console.log(xml);
    trainigsControl.setParameter("fetchXML", xml);
    trainigsControl.refresh();
    return xml;
}


function GetRelatedProfiles() {
    return Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("new_contact_new_profil", "?$select=new_profilid&$filter=contactid eq " + guid).then(
        function success(result) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
                relatedProfiles.push(result.entities[i]["new_profilid"]);
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            // handle error conditions
        }
    );
}

function getUniques(arr) {
    var uniques = [];
    arr.forEach(item => {
        if (uniques.indexOf(item) === -1) {
            uniques.push(item);
        }
    });
    arr = uniques;
}

function GetRelatedTatigkeiten() {
    return Promise.all(relatedProfiles.map(profile =>
        Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("new_new_profil_new_azttigkeit", `?$select=new_azttigkeitid&$filter=new_profilid eq ${profile}`).then(
            function success(result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
                    relatedTatigkeiten.push(result.entities[i]["new_azttigkeitid"]);
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                // handle error conditions
            }
        )
    )).then(() => getUniques(relatedTatigkeiten));
}

function GetRelatedBetriebsmittel() {
    return Promise.all(relatedProfiles.map(profile =>
        Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("new_new_betriebsmittel_new_profil", "?$select=new_betriebsmittelid&$filter=new_profilid eq " + profile).then(
            function success(result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
                        relatedBetriebsmittelGruppen.push(result.entities[i]["new_betriebsmittelid"])
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                // handle error conditions
            }
        )
    )).then(() => getUniques(relatedTatigkeiten));
}

function GetBetriebsmittelRelatedUnterweisungTypen() {
    return Promise.all(relatedBetriebsmittelGruppen.map(betriebsmittel =>
        Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("new_new_betriebsmittel_new_schulungstyp", "?$select=new_schulungstypid&$filter=new_betriebsmittelid eq " + betriebsmittel).then(
            function success(result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
                    unterweisungTypen.push(result.entities[i]["new_schulungstypid"]);
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                // handle error conditions
            }
        )
    )).then(() => getUniques(unterweisungTypen));
}

function GetTatigkeitenRelatedUnterweisungTypen() {
    return Promise.all(relatedTatigkeiten.map(tatigkeiten =>
        Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("new_new_schulungstyp_new_azttigkeit", "?$select=new_schulungstypid&$filter=new_azttigkeitid eq " + tatigkeiten).then(
            function success(result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
                        unterweisungTypen.push(result.entities[i]["new_schulungstypid"]);
                }
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                // handle error conditions
            }
        ))).then(() => getUniques(unterweisungTypen));
    }
```

}